# Unity: From "Normal mode" to "VR mode" back to "Normal mode"

Tags: unity, virtual-reality

I want to change my unity application per runtime to a "Vr-Mode" and then switch it back. 
Since the VR-Mode changed the camera behaviour and messes with the system i want to use i can not start my program with "project settings" where VR is not active.

Is this even possible?

Is there some kind of a "magic bool" somewhere which toggles the vr on / off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use these lib at first

```
using UnityEngine.VR;
```

and then in

`void Start () {
        VRSettings.enabled = false;
    }`

it will work for unity5.6 and further versions as well.

Comment: XRSettings.enabled = true;
XRSettings.enabled = false;